# Maintaining an ordered list of time-slices that can be modified (list should still be ordered)

Tags: java, collections

So , I have a problem where there are various objects of a specific type are present in an **ArrayList** as present below,

```
...
//Class definition
class Params
{
  long startTimeMillis;
  long endTimeMillis;
  String currentState;

 .. correponding getters and setters are present here ..
}
....

ArrayList<Params> activities=new ArrayList<>();

Params h1= new Params();        
h1.setStartTimeMillis(1435939200000L);//"16:00"
h1.setEndTimeMillis(1435941000000L);//"16:30"
h1.setCurrentState("C");

Params h2= new Params();        
h2.setStartTimeMillis(1435941000000L);//"16:30"
h2.setEndTimeMillis(1435941900000L);//"16:45"
h2.setCurrentState("B");

Params h3= new Params();        
h3.setStartTimeMillis(1435941900000L);//"16:45"
h3.setEndTimeMillis(1435942500000L);//"16:55"
h3.setCurrentState("A");

Params h4= new Params();        
h4.setStartTimeMillis(1435942500000L);//"16:55"
h4.setEndTimeMillis(1435942800000L);//"17:00"
h4.setCurrentState("B");

Params h5= new Params();        
h5.setStartTimeMillis(1435942800000L);//"17:00"
h5.setEndTimeMillis(1435943400000L);//"17:10"
h5.setCurrentState("C");

activities.add(h1);
activities.add(h2);
activities.add(h3);
activities.add(h4);
activities.add(h5);
```

Now , there are various cases in which I can increase or decrease:

- Start Time of a specific object
- End Time of a specific object
- Both if the object is present between two or more activities.

e.g.

Example 1:

in case I modify object `h2` such that start time of `h2` (**16:30**) is decreased by 10 mins then the end time of `h1` should be decreased by the same i.e. `h1` end time would be **16:20**

Example 2:

in case I modify object `h2` such that end time of `h2` (**16:45**) is increased by 10 mins i.e **16:55** then object `h3` should be removed from the list as it is occupied completely by `h2`.

**I/P:** 
I always have the modified start and end time for every object in two diff variables but the problem is to modify the objects as mentioned in the cases above at runtime and update the arraylist accordingly.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes I am not able to implement the mentioned cases/examples those I have mentioned.

Comment: Is the ordering of objects defined by start-time? Are the time-slices required to be mutually exclusive?

Comment: @VivinPaliath yes the ordering is defined by start time and the time-slices are mutually exclusive i.e. if one increment/decrement it cuts from/add to other.

Comment: @prateek - What have you done to solve the problem yourself, so far?

Comment: @AndyThomas I tried to get positions for various objects but confused with how to modify one and remove another dynamically

Comment: @prateek - It can be useful to show the relevant code you've written so far. The code you've included appears to be the initialization of your data, rather than the code you're asking about.

Comment: @AndyThomas didn't want to go further with some manual approach of adding and subtracting values of milliseconds , will update code in the post though

Comment: @VivinPaliath Please cover the case mentioned in the comment to your answer .. it is failing in the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use a `TreeSet` and define the ordering for `Param`. To do this, you have to make `Param` implement `Comparable` and then provide implementations for `hashCode` and `equals` as well.

You can then modify an item and then navigate the set to find the preceding and succeeding item. My solution assumes that there aren't any overlapping times and it will handle your second case as well (removing invalid time-slices).

First we need to have `Param` implement `Comparable<Param>`:

```
public class Param implements Comparable<Param> {

    //Public just for demo purposes and brevity
    public int start;
    public int end;

    public Param(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Param o) {
        //Needs to be consistent with equals!!
        int result = this.start - o.start;
        if(result == 0) {
            result = (this.end - this.start) - (o.end - o.start);
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + start;
        result = 31 * result + end;  
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        ... // null check, reference check etc.
        Param p = (Param) o;
        return this.start == p.start && this.end == p.end;
    }
}
```

Now all the hard work is done! You can use methods from `TreeSet` to find the right items and then modify them. Here's some example code.

```
  NavigableSet<Param> pset = new TreeSet<Param>();

  Param p1 = new Param(10, 20);
  Param p2 = new Param(20, 30);
  Param p3 = new Param(30, 50);
  Param p4 = new Param(50, 60);

  pset.add(p1);
  pset.add(p2);
  pset.add(p3);
  pset.add(p4);

  System.out.println(pset);      

  int sdiff = -2;
  int ediff = 2;      

  //Find the item we want, as well as the preceding and succeeding items
  Param p = pset.floor(new Param(20, 30));      
  Param lower = pset.lower(p);
  Param higher = pset.higher(p);      

  //Remove the item from the set and modify it
  pset.remove(p);
  p.start += sdiff;
  p.end += ediff;      

  //Add only if it is valid
  if(p.start < p.end) {
      pset.add(p);    
  }      

  //If we have a preceding item
  if(lower != null) {
      //Remove, modify, and add back to set
      pset.remove(lower);
      lower.end += sdiff;
      if(lower.start < lower.end) {
          pset.add(lower);
      }    
  }

  //Same case as lower
  if(higher != null) {
      pset.remove(higher);
      higher.start += ediff;          
      if(higher.start < higher.end) {
          pset.add(higher);
      }    
  }

  System.out.println(pset);
```

Running this code gives us:

```
[[10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 50], [50, 60]]
[[10, 22], [22, 28], [28, 50], [50, 60]]
```

This code works for invalid time-slices as well as the following examples will demonstrate:

```
int sdiff = -20;
int ediff = 20;
```

outputs:

```
[[10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 50], [50, 60]]
[[0, 50], [50, 60]]
```

It will also work if you have modified the element itself in such a way that its time-slice is invalid:

```
int sdiff = 5;
int ediff = -5;      

Param p = pset.floor(new Param(10, 20));
```

gives us:

```
[[10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 50], [50, 60]]
[[15, 30], [30, 50], [50, 60]]
```

And:

```
int sdiff = 5;
int ediff = -10;      

Param p = pset.floor(new Param(10, 20));
```

gives us:

```
[[10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 50], [50, 60]]
[[10, 30], [30, 50], [50, 60]]
```

This particular solution won't work if you modify an element such that it spans more than one slice. But with a slight modification, you can get it to handle those cases too. This is where using a sorted structure really helps, because it would be kind of a nightmare to do this with a list. The modification involves using a `while` loop instead of an `if` and running through the loop as long as there are elements that need to be modified. The loop also checks to see if we ended up in the "middle" of a slice and if so it adjusts the start/end time appropriately:

```
//As long as we have elements to modify
while(lower != null) {
    Param nextLower = null;

    //Remove, modify, and add back to set if valid
    pset.remove(lower);
    lower.end += sdiff;

    if(lower.start < lower.end) {
        //The modified slice is valid, so add it back
        pset.add(lower);                   
    } else if(lower.start > lower.end) {
        //The modified slice is not valid and so we're not
        //going to add it. But it looks like we might have
        //encroached on the space of the slice that precedes
        //"lower" (at least; we may have extended past even
        //more, possibly all the way up to and past the
        //beginning)
        nextLower = pset.lower(p);
        if(nextLower != null && p.start == nextLower.start) {
            //It looks like we took up the space of the preceding
            //slice exactly (i.e., we are flush against it) and
            //so we don't need to do anything.
            nextLower = null;
        } else if(nextLower != null) {
            //It looks like we took up the space of the preceding
            //slice and then some. Let's adjust sdiff to reflect
            //that.
            sdiff = p.start - nextLower.end;                  
        }                            
    }

    lower = nextLower;
}

  //Similar to lower
  while(higher != null) {
      Param nextHigher = null;

      pset.remove(higher);
      higher.start += ediff;

      //Need to check for the additional case where the modified element's
      //end time could supersede a "higher" element's end time.
      if(higher.start < higher.end && higher.end > p.end) {
          pset.add(higher);              
      } else if(higher.start > higher.end || higher.end <= p.end) {
          nextHigher = pset.higher(p);
          if(nextHigher != null && p.end == nextHigher.start) {
              nextHigher = null;
          } else if(nextHigher != null) {
              ediff = p.end - nextHigher.start;                  
          }
      }

      higher = nextHigher;
  }
```

This algorithm won't work in the case where you, for example, change `[30, 40]` to be `[0, 5]` or `[5, 15]`. In this situation you end up with a space where `[30, 40]` used to be, and it's not clearly defined how that space should be filled up. Should `[20, 30]` change to `[20, 40]`, or should `[40, 50]` change to `[30, 50]`? Or how about something like `[20, 35]` and `[35, 50]`? As long as the modified range contains all or part of the original range, this algorithm will work.

Comment: It works great! but as you have said .. when I try to skip more then one time slice the same doesn't work.. Can you help with how can I move further where I want to skip as many time slices. Yes the data is in order

Comment: @prateek Before you do that you will have to figure out what to do with that missing time-slice. If you move a slice, how should that space be occupied? Which adjacent slices should grow to fill it?

Comment: No space should be left as increasing slice will acquire all for next ones . let's say we have [10,20] [20,30] [30,40] [40,50] and I increase first slice i.e. [10,20] such that 20 + 30 then the only data should be [10,50] . The same should work if I subtract from the last slice so that it becomes equal to first slice.

Comment: Can you update the above code to acquire the case that I want .. Don't have any clue to move ahead with the same and iteratively remove elements further. I must accept this answer if it fulfills this case as well

Comment: @prateek the above code will work for that case. I was talking about a situation where, for example, you changed [30, 40] to be [0, 5] or [5, 15]. If should [20, 30] change to [20, 40] or should [40, 50] change to [30, 50]? Or should it be something like [20, 35] and [35, 50]? That's what this solution does not handle.

Comment: This won't be the case as all the elements are connected to each other the end of one is start for another . As you are saying the above code works for the scenario I am talking about but when executed doesn't remove the objects from the end e.g.  for input `10,20

20,30

30,50

50,60

60,80

80,90

--- o/p is -------

10,90

50,60

60,80

80,90`

Comment: @prateek Are you sure? Did you add my modifications (i.e., the solution with `while` instead of `if`). Because what I get is `[[10, 20], [20, 30], [30, 50], [50, 60], [60, 80]]` initially. Then when I change `[10, 20]` to `[10, 90]` I end up with `[[10, 90]]`.

Answer (score 0):

This will modify your start time

```
public void modifyStart(Params toModify,int increment,ArrayList<Params> list){
    int index = list.indexOf(toModify);
    int timeStart=toModify.getStartTimeMillis()+increment;
    toModify.setStartTimeMillis(timeStart);
    for(int i=index-1;i>=0;i--){ //removing all previous
        if(timeStart<list.get(i).getStartTimeMillis()){
            list.remove(i);
            index--;
        }else{
             break;
        }
    }
    if(index==0){
        return;
    }
    Params previous = list.get(index-1);
    previous.setEndTimeMillis(previous.getEndTimeMillis()+increment);
    if(toModify.getStartTimeMillis()>toModify.getEndTimeMillis()){ //removes yourself
        list.remove(toModify);
    }
}
```

End time will be very similar

Note: not tested, just showing an idea

Comment: will check with the same data as posted in my question, accept if it works

Comment: I can see it wont work properly if start time will "cover" two or more events before, I have edited it but still not sure about 100% working @prateek

Comment: You can use the dataset I have posted in the question for a pseudocode and pass the list as is.