# How does using logic operators populate a var?

Tags: javascript

Let's take a look at this code:

```
var token = (req.body && req.body.access_token) ||
            (req.query && req.query.access_token) ||
            req.headers['x-access-token'];
```

[Taken from here.](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-json-web-tokens-node-js/)

Shouldn't this return a boolean? What most confuses me is the chained AND and OR statements. I'm reading this as:

> The variable token equals the boolean whether `req.body` AND `req.body.access_token` exist. OR, if they don't exist, then it equals the boolean whether `req.query` AND `req.query.access_token` exist. OR, if they don't exist, it equals the value of `req.headers['x-access-token']`.

Furthermore, if we analyze just this piece:

```
var token = req.body && req.body.access_token;
```

What keeps the `token` from being set to `req.body`?

Comment: No, the boolean operators don't return a boolean in Javascript.

Comment: Can you address my edit as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really evaluating a boolean expression and assigning that to `token`. What you have there is a kind of shorthand `if-else`. Let's break it down:

```
(req.body && req.body.access_token)
```

If `req.body` is ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (in this particular case it is ensuring that it is not `null` or `undefined`, probably) then it will assign `req.body.access_token` to `token`. The expression will short-circuit here and will not proceed.

Otherwise, it looks at the next case:

```
(req.query && req.query.access_token)
```

This is the same as the above; except in this case it assigns `req.query.access_token` to `token` if `req.query` is "truthy". It will also short-circuit here unless "falsy".

```
req.headers['x-access-token'];
```

This is the final clause. If none of the preceding cases are true, it will assign the value of `req.headers['x-access-token']` to `token`.

In the traditional form, it would look like this:

```
var token;
if(req.body && req.body.access_token) {
    token = req.body.access_token;
} else if(req.query && req.query.access_token) {
    token = req.query.access_token;
} else {
    token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
}
```

> What keeps the token from being set to req.body?

The expression is:

```
var token = req.body && req.body.access_token;
```

It won't set `token` to `req.body`. Here, `req.body` is kind of acting as a flag. We don't want to do `req.body.access_token` directly because `req.body` could be `null` or `undefined`. So what it's doing here is saying "if `req.body` is non-null/defined, then assign `req.body.access_token` to `token`". Realize that if the first term of an `&&` is true, the second term must still be evaluated because the only time an AND is true is when both operands are true. However the advantage here is that "evaluating" the second term returns the value of that term as well, which is what set as `token` eventually.

More explicitly, the above expression can be represented as:

```
if(req.body !== null || typeof req.body !== "undefined") {
    token = req.body.access_token;
}
```

But in JavaScript you can simply check `if(some_var)` and that won't run the code in the `if` block if `some_var` is `undefined` or `null`. But you have to be careful because legitimate values like `0` or an empty-string are "falsy", and you could end up ignoring them.

Comment: More info on [**Short-circuit evaluation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation). Perfect answer, +1.

Comment: I'm assuming you can only get this behaviour with logical OR (`||`) statements? I.e. you can't short-circuit an expression with AND statements?

Comment: @KennyWorden I made this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbpa118L/) to demonstrate what happens with `&&`.

Comment: Take some time to read the link I posted in my first comment. They give examples to show how it works.

Comment: @KennyWorden you can use it with `&&`; the value of the final term will be returned if all preceding terms evaluate to `true`. Otherwise the result will be `false`.

Comment: @VivinPaliath http://stackoverflow.com/a/31444174/1503130 please update your answer for the query ... I am really stuck here.. an urgent requirement has come to me..